# Prevent Windows from shutting down or rebooting

Tags: windows, gratis, power-management

I am looking for a program that reliably prevents the computer from shutting down. This can be useful in various cases:

- during PowerPoint presentations
- while running a huge download over night
- when backing up an entire disk

The tool should

- be gratis
- run on Windows 7 and higher
- prevent shutdown done via the `shutdown` command
- prevent reboot due to Windows updates
- prevent shutdown via power button switch
- prevent reboot of other installers (whatever software might cause this)
- just do this and not a bunch of other stuff like some system enhancement tools do

I have tried the Registry switch `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers` but it was not very helpful and applies to Windows Updates only, not to other software.

Answer (score 3):

[Don't sleep](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep) is a free tool that is small (200 kB on disk, 5 MB in RAM) and does the job. It can run in the system tray, so it does not disturb you. It prevents shutdown, reboot, standy, hibernate and even turning off the monitor (configurable).

[image: Don't sleep screenshot]

Though it has links to other system tools, these are just shortcuts and not built-in overhead which is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [Shut It!](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/prevent-cancel-and-abort-a-windows-system-shutdown-or-restart-when-application-is-running/2/)

> Shut It! is a bit of a dual mode shutdown utility because in addition
>   to the standard monitoring function of intercepting shutdowns and
>   restarts etc, it can also watch for specific application processes or
>   windows and perform a different action for those that match. For
>   example, you could let the system shutdown normally if none of the
>   checked programs match, but cancel the shutdown or warn you beforehand
>   if something matches from the predefined list.

The number of actions you can perform on a shutdown check is slightly different depending on your operating system. Windows XP and newer have **Do nothing**, **Cancel** and **Show warning** dialog available.

[image]

In the tray menu is also an option to schedule a shutdown/logoff and there’s quick access to all the standard shutdown

Answer (score 0):

What about a script or batch file that runs `shutdown -a` (Abort Shutdown) repeatedly during the time period? Could be made into a Scheduled Task or launched from a batch file.